# Calculate the percentage for each row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as the following. I want to calculate the percentage for each row. See the output. I feel `sum over()` may help, but I am not sure how exactly it works.

Input

```
PK col1 col2
-------------
1   1   4
2   5   10
```

Output

```
PK col1 col2
---------------
1   0.2  0.8
2   0.33 0.67
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sum up the values and divide.

```
select pk,1.0*col1/(col1+col2),1.0*col2/(col1+col2)
from tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

`sum() over()` works across rows, and what you have works on the same row. Instead you would use something like this:

```
select 
    pk
  , col1 = (col1+.0)/(col1+col2)
  , col2 = (col2+.0)/(col1+col2)
from t
```

Comment: what will be the output if col1+.0?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu It is to avoid integer division, if the columns are integers. Adding `+.0` coerces the value into a `decimal` data type.

Comment: should you just wary about the output rather than what's to be calculated?   1/2 is always a float   ... 1.2/3 is always a float

Comment: @maSTAShuFu `1/2` = `0`, because they are integers. `1.2/3` is `numeric(7,6)`. **Demo**: http://rextester.com/SRTCJI56708